# Cutting down a .jar file to lighten an Android app

Tags: java, android, jar, size, reduce

Background: In the process of creating an android application, I am messing around with different hashing techniques and speeds. I *was* using the Android native stuff until I found SpongyCastle ( i.e. BouncyCastle ), which turned out to be a lot faster. The SpongyCastle .jar file is fairly large, and my .apk is over 800kb with just the jar and a couple of testing classes ( and all of the necessary android fluff).

Question pt 1: Is this normal for .jar files to do to an APK? Do they usually bloat out the file?

Question pt 2: Is there any way for me ( either via source or jar ) to cut down the file? I'm only using the SHA256 and SHA1 hash schemes, and I have not been able to figure out how to use just those two hash schemes without including the entire jar.

Thoughts?

**Edited:** ProGuard works wonders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).  It *excels* at trimming down parts of dependencies that you don't use.  It's specifically mentioned for use on Android applications [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

(I contribute to Guava, which is a pretty big library, but a lot of people want to use it for Android.  We point them to ProGuard.)

Comment: Had to do another couple of changes ( gorram proguard.cfg was nowhere to be found ), but that made it happen. Ta muchly!